# Turbo stream partial rendering as plain text in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, turbo

I'm building a new Rails 7 app and trying to follow the intended default uses of turbo streams for ajax content replacements (and stimulus where other JS control is needed). This is my first time using Turbo Drive.

I'm also using view components (https://viewcomponent.org/).

The problem is that the response from the server appears to be treated as plain text by the browser. I've tried in Chrome and Brave and the response mime-type is as expected (`text/vnd.turbo-stream.html` per the browser reported response header).  Further, the browser console reports that `window.Turbo` is defined so Turbo seems to be available on the client side JS.

As a starting point, this is a snippet of html rendered during initial display before an intended operation:

```html
<div class='grid grid-cols-2 gap-4'>
  <div class='card bg-base-100 shadow-x1 mb-4'>
    <div class='card-body'>...some text here...</div>
    <div class='card-actions justify-center'>
      <form class="form-control w-full max-w-xs pb-2" action="/someroute.turbo_stream" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get">
        <div class='input-group'>
          <input placeholder="Bring out your text" class="input input-secondary w-full" type="text" name="location_text" id="location_text" />
          <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Button Legend" class="btn btn-secondary w-fit px-2" data-disable-with="Button Legend" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
.
.
.
<turbo-frame data-turbo='true' id='some-container'>
  <div class='border rounded p-4 mb-4'>
    <div class='text-center mb-2'>...some text...</div>
  </div>
</turbo-frame>
```

The intention is that `some-container` html be replaced upon submitting the button form (see `<input type="submit"...>` above). Note that I intend it to be a GET operation (see the <form ...> element).

That part works fine. The button is pressed and my controller is triggered as expected.

controller:

```rb
def show
  # ...other code to prepare content...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.turbo_stream
    format.html do
      raise 'unexpectedly HTML format'
    end
  end
end
```

show.turbo_stream.haml:

```
= turbo_stream.replace '#some-container' do
  = render SomeContainerComponent.new(<some arguments>) # just for interior content
```

and just in case, here's the HAML for the component (that same component was used to initially render the page and intention is just to update it):

```
%turbo-frame#some-container{data: {turbo: 'true'}}
  .border.rounded.p-4.mb-4
    = render(AnotherComponent.new(<some arguments>))
```

From what I've seen, I should really need the turbo-frame element since the id of `some-container` should be sufficient.  And I shouldn't need the `data-turbo=true` either (I haven't disabled Turbo as far as I can tell.). I've tried it with and without those pieces without any appreciable change.

The only other thing that seems relevant is to share that this is the line in the page view layout for involving the JS:

```
= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbo-track': 'reload', defer: true
```

Still, when I submit the form, the response from the server replaces the page with a plain text rendering of the HTML intended to be used to replace the `#some-container` element and looks otherwise properly formed.

Here's what that HTML response looks like on the browser:

```html
<turbo-stream action="replace" target="#some-container"><template><turbo-frame data-turbo='true' id='some-container'>
.
.
.
...HTML elements for the content to be displayed...
.
.
.
</turbo-frame>

</template></turbo-stream>
```

Since the form submits and triggers the controller, it seems that this is really just a JS related issue with Turbo. I can always fallback to the older UJS form with `remote: true` and explicitly handle `ajax:success`, but wanted to make what is apparently the new recommended way to do this in Rails 7 with Turbo.

Any advice how to get it to stop rendering the response snippet in plain text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add format extension to url. Turbo only works with [html](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/blob/v7.1.0/src/core/url.ts#L22-L28) anyway. If extension is `x?html` or empty, *turbo* kicks [in](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/blob/v7.1.0/src/core/url.ts#L36). If it is something else, a regular request is [sent](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/blob/v7.1.0/src/core/drive/navigator.ts#L30). Notice when submitting your form the page actually does a full refresh. Request to `/page.turbo_stream` renders a partial with a *<turbo-stream>* tag (no layout, no javascript) and a header `Content-Type: text/vnd.turbo-stream.html;`. Because it is not *text/html*, browser renders it as plain text.

To start, just use *<turbo-frame>*.

```
<%= form_with url: "/path",
    method: :get,
    data: { turbo_frame: :form_response } do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<%= turbo_frame_tag :form_response %>
```

Response is in html format:

```
format.html { render :something }
```

and it can look like this:

```
<!-- Anything else on this page outside of this frame will be discarded -->
<%= turbo_frame_tag :form_response do %>
  <dialog open>
    <p>Updated</p>
    <form method="dialog"><button type="submit">Close</button></form>
  </dialog>
<% end %>
```

---

*GET* streams are only supported in the recent beta `v7.2.0-beta.1`
*https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/pull/612*

```
# Gemfile

# gem "turbo-rails"
gem "turbo-rails", github: "hotwired/turbo-rails", branch: "turbo-7-2-0"
```

**Update**

*GET* streams have landed in `turbo` https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/releases/tag/v7.2.0

Update `turbo-rails` to [`v1.3.0`](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/releases/tag/v1.3.0)

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer, esp. with the advice re the beta! It looks like I didn't need Streams at all then, just Frames. I'll give this a go today!

Comment: It worked!  Thank you!  Definitely turns out to be straightforward once you pointed me in the right direction.  

One note, and I'm sure this ViewComponents issue but sharing so it's known:  I had to add `include Turbo::FramesHelper` into my component (which now I can generalize to all my components for all the Turbo helpers) to make `turbo_frame_tag` available.  Apparently the base gem (or its ViewComponent::Base) doesn't bring that in from the ActionView context.

Just throwing in